# Nouns  for 'living' and 'working' which sound more category-like?

Tags: word-choice

I have the following categories (for a forum):

- Entertainment
- Transportation
- Business
- Travel
- Legal
- Relationships
- Technology
- Politics

I also wanted to add two more categories:

One about **living** in general (getting a house, getting use to a new country, etc.)

And other about **working** in general (getting a job, complaints about work, etc.)

Which are the right nouns for them?

(or is it correct to just use 'Living' and 'Working/Employment' as 'Categories')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think *employment* is probably your best choice for *working*. As for *living*, *personal finance* or *life style* may be your best choice.

Comment: Thanks, I will go for employment then. But I'm not sure about 'Personal Finance', I also include posts that are not related to money too (like finding a house, getting use to the culture of another country, etc.

Comment: "Lifestyle" is a possibility then.

Comment: I think I want to go for something which is related to everything that happens in getting and living in a house?

Comment: "Household" or "Family", maybe. I think "Lifestyle" is best actually. I can't quite find the absolutely perfect word.

Comment: @janoChen Sorry, I changed the meaning of the category. Now it is only referring to getting and maintaining a house, family, transportation, etc.

Comment: OK, I think I can use 'Household.' and have another category called 'Transportation.'